# Ionic 3: 'String is not defined" error in binding variable to ion-icon

Tags: javascript, angular, windows, ionic-framework, ionic3

I looked at the other examples and suggestions when binding an Ionic icon to a variable but I keep getting an error that says 'String is not defined" from the following:

html:

```
<ion-item class="card">
   <ion-icon [name]="myIcon"></ion-icon>
   <button ion-item id="startBtn"></button>
</ion-item>
```

I'm attempting to change the icon whenever I run a certain function

ts:

```
export class HomePage {

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

}    

ionViewDidLoad() {

var time = {
    hours: 0,
    minutes: 0,
    seconds: 0,
    cseconds: 0,
    running: false,
    start: -1
  }

 var myButton = document.querySelector('#startBtn')
 myButton.addEventListener('click', setToggleButton)
  
 function setToggleButton() {
    if (time.running === false) {
      console.log('changing the icon');
      myIcon: string = "play";
    }
    else {
    console.log('changing the icon');
    myIcon: string = "stop";
    }
  }
```

According to what I understand, this should work but my Ionic App returns this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqbwF.jpg)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: String is a keyword in javascript,you need to use other names

Comment: please Define "myIcon:String" above the constructor and then use in function like "this.myIcon = 'Play' "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your variable *myIcon* above your constructor

> myIcon: String;

And use it below like this.myIcon = "yourIcon"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above suggestions. I was able to solve it with an additional step.

First I had to declare as suggested above the constructor:

```
myIcon: String;
```

Then in ionViewDidLoad() added:

```
var that = this;
```

Final code looks like this

```
export class HomePage {
myIcon: String;

constructor(public navCtrl: 
NavController) {

}    

ionViewDidLoad() {

var that = this;

var time = {
 hours: 0,
 minutes: 0,
 seconds: 0,
 cseconds: 0,
 running: false,
 start: -1
}

var myButton = 
document.querySelector('#startBtn')
myButton.addEventListener('click', 
setToggleButton)

function setToggleButton() {
 if (time.running === false) {
  console.log('changing the icon');
  that.myIcon = "play";
 }
 else {
  console.log('changing the icon');
  that.myIcon = "stop";
 }
}
```